# Can wizard's staff of defense class feature stack with Wizard Utility 2 Shield on the same triggering effect?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, defense, interrupt

**Staff of Defense** class feature:

> ...once per encounter as an immediate
> interrupt, you gain a bonus to defense
> against one attack equal to your
> Constitution modifier.  You can
> declare the bonus after the Dungeon
> Master has already told you the
> damage.

**Shield** Wizard Utility 2:

> Immediate Interrupt Personal
>
> Tigger: You are hit by an attack
>
> Effect:  You gain a +4 power bonues to AC and
> Reflex defense until the end of your
> next turn.

Could you activate these powers against the same triggering attack and thus stack them against the same attack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**,

You may only use one Immediate Action<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=120)</sup> per round.

Reminder - you cannot use an Immediate Action on your own turn.

Comment: Not sure where using an IA during your turn comes into play here, but good response.

Comment: @Iszi - it's one of the most commonly forgotten little rules in my group.  Last month someone tried to use **Shield** after drawing an AO during his own turn in my game.  I thought it'd be a good idea to toss it in here as a reminder.

Comment: Just to expand on the answer, if by some means you are permitted to use both in the same round, they should stack, as Shield is a power bonus, while Staff of Defense is an untyped bonus

Comment: @Iszi - you've never been hit on your turn before?  You should move around more, trigger some AO's and whatnot.  It's fun!

Answer (score 2):

As Pat mentioned above, you are unable to use both at the same turn due to the action economy.

EDITED: I withdrew my argument regarding the utilization of action points. You **cannot** substitute a regular action for an immediate one, as I recalled falsely.

However, it should be noted that technically **the stacking of such effects would be valid** should their activation action cost allow them to be used within a certain time frame.

> To conclude with an answer to the actual question (whether they
>   **stack** or not):
>
> **Yes**, the latter is a power-type bonus but the former is untyped, meaning that it stacks with everything in accordance to the stacking
>   rules in the PHB.

Comment: @JohnAthanasiou what you may be recalling is the ability to use an action point to *ready* an action to be used later in a round. Using this action also consumes youre immediate action.

Comment: @waxeagle That is more than likely. I will keep that in mind next time I play 4e.