# Why can't I pick the Staff of Defense option for my Wizard?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, class-feature

I am using the dnd insider to create my level two Wizard (Mage - enchanter) and I'm noticing that I certain abilities, feats or spells that were recommended I take in the Wizards handbook (such as the winged horde spell, freezing burst, horrid whispers, or daily powers like watery sphere!).  In fact, the insider character builder doesn't even let me take the Staff of Defense option.  It's not even offered to me??

Can someone please explain to me why I'm not able to select some of these powers/feats that were recommended in the handbook?  Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: can you link to the guide you were looking at? Staff of defense is a class feature not a feat/power.  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/can-wizards-staff-of-defense-class-feature-stack-with-wizard-utility-2-shield-o

Comment: http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28817645/Archmages_Ascension_-_The_Wizards_Handbook

Comment: are you using the "custom" option or the "create" option? looks like they've resolved your issue, but I'd definitely make sure you use teh "custom" option when creating a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Staff of Defense is for Arcanists, not Mages.**

Wizard is a general class, with a set of powers, but several possible "builds", including Mage and Arcanist. The original build of the wizard (Arcanist) gets the Implement Mastery option, which is what you use to get Staff of Defense. Mage is the Essentials build, and gets to pick from a variety of different styles (including Enchanter) *instead* of getting an Implement Mastery.

I *think* there's a feat that Mages can take at paragon tier that allows them to acquire an Implement Mastery.

TLDR: There are several "types" of wizard, and only arcanists can get Staff of Defense.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  Is that the same reason that I can't select some of the powers such as winged horde or watery sphere?

Comment: Usually E-classes don't get all the power options of the parent class, but this is made up for by having stronger class features. I know martial e-classes have a feat (martial Cross training) that they can use to lose a power strike and gain a parent class encounter power.

Comment: @BruceA see my comment above, that's usually a consequence of choosing the "Create" or "quick" option